# Some (but not all) stuff still logged to /var/log/nginx/error.log despite being configured to log elsewhere

Tags: nginx, logging

here is scee.conf -

```
pid ./pid;

error_log ./error_log debug;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  access_log ./access_log;
  server {
    listen 31415;
  }
}
```

I run it using

```
nginx -c scee.conf -p .
```

(run from the directory in which it resides)

Most stuff gets logged to `error.log` in the same directory as the config file, but mysteriously the following line continues to be logged to `/var/log/nginx/error.log` every time nginx is restarted -

```
2015/05/06 21:41:39 [notice] 2231#0: signal process started
```

or similar.

This is annoying as it requires /var/log/nginx to be writable by the user running nginx. What is going on here?

Output of nginx -V

```
nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
built by gcc 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_spdy_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module
```

What is the --error-log-path compiler flag doing here? Does it simply control the default location of logs if you don't have a error_log directive in your config file?

Comment: I have the same problem. `error_log` is defined at the very top so any server should inherit it. But `nginx -s reload` still puts signals in the default error location

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you have more than one server block in your config. In my case I think it was caused by having an HTTP redirect like below. The HTTP requests were being logged in the default log path, but the HTTPS requests were logged where I expected.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    access_log /path/to/my.log;

    ...

}
```

Comment: I don't think this is likely. That file is the entirety of the config, unless nginx additionally pulls in config from a default location - that's why we reduce problems to SCEEs. Also, the issue is with the error log, which properly doesn't belong to either server block, and not the access log, which is in the server block.